# (UBuntu)SED , can't expand variable

Tags: ubuntu, sed

I can't seem to expand a variable (LINKNAME) inside sed... I've used double quotes, changed the delimiter, but I still can't get it to work.

```
LINKNAME=$(echo -e "${NEW_MOVIES_DIRLIST}" | sed -r 's,FOLDERS_TO_BE_SCANNED/HDD-EXTENDED.-SD./,,g')

NEW_MOVIES_DIRLIST=$(echo -e "${NEW_MOVIES_DIRLIST}" | sed "s,$,LINKNAME,g")
```

It won't expand LINKNAME, any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `$` before `LINKNAME` so that it would get expand.

```
NEW_MOVIES_DIRLIST=$(echo -e "${NEW_MOVIES_DIRLIST}" | sed "s,$,$LINKNAME,g")
```

Comment: OR `sed "s,$,${LINKNAME},g"`

Comment: It won't work... NEW_MOVIES_DIRLIST won't generate anything after i give it $ or $()..

Answer (score 0):

Could be multiple things wrong here:

```
    LINKNAME=$(
            echo -e "${NEW_MOVIES_DIRLIST}" |
            sed -r 's,FOLDERS_TO_BE_SCANNED/HDD-EXTENDED.-SD./,,g'
    )       

    NEW_MOVIES_DIRLIST=$(
            echo -e "${NEW_MOVIES_DIRLIST}" | sed "s,$,LINKNAME,g"
    )
```

1) Does ${NEW_MOVIES_DIRLIST} contain a list?  If so, this whole technique won't
 work.

2) It is not clear to me what in "${NEW_MOVIES_DIRLIST}" is to be substutied wit
h "${LINKNAME}".

Could we see a couple of input lines and a couple of your expected output?